# Curl+file scheme not returns headers in PHP 7.3+

Tags: php

Using this code:

```
$ch = curl_init('file:///c:/foo/bar/baz.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

$headers = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($headers);
```

In PHP 7.2 (and olders) returns:

> ```
> string(88) "Content-Length: 57
> Accept-ranges: bytes
> Last-Modified: Sun, 29 Dec 2019 05:31:32 GMT
> "
> ```

In PHP 7.3 and PHP 7.4 returns empty string:

> ```
> string(0) ""
> ```

I'm using this code to get file sizes too large to avoid limitations, but my question is not quite how to fix this but whether this is a bug or a permanent change in new versions of PHP?